# PhoneGap iOS CDVViewController not responding to touches

Tags: ios, cordova, touch

So I have created my own UIViewController and placed the following lines inside viewDidLoad. The view draws just fine but is unresponsive to touch. What might cause this problem?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CDVViewController* viewController = [CDVViewController new];
    viewController.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
    [self.view addSubview:viewController.view];

    [self addChildViewController:viewController];
}
```

I'm using PhoneGap 2.8/2.9 and iOS 6.1

Comment: If you're using Phonegap why do you need to create your own UIViewController? Maybe I don't understand what you're trying to do, but with Phonegap you should really only need to worry about the files you put inside the www directory to create your application. And why are you using two versions of Phonegap?

Comment: A CDVViewController will be running alongside a native UIViewController in a UITabbarController. I'm only using one. I tried both.